Remove pester 3.4.0 - Powershell
I'm trying to remove pester v3.4.0 but nothing I'm doing is working. I can't manually  remove the folder as admin. I can't run uninstall-module normally or as admin and I can't use this script:
# folders where PowerShell looks for modules:
$paths = $env:PSModulePath -split ';'
# finding actual module folders
$modules = Get-ChildItem -Path $paths -Depth 0 -Directory | Sort-Object -Property Name

$modules | 
  Select-Object -Property Name, @{N='Parent';E={$_.Parent.FullName}}, FullName |
  Out-GridView -Title 'Select module(s) to permanently delete' -PassThru |
  Out-GridView -Title 'Do you REALLY want to remove the modules below? CTRL+A and OK to confirm' -PassThru |
  Remove-Item -Path { $_.FullName } -Recurse -Force

I just keep getting the following for every file in the folder.
+   Remove-Item -Path { $_.FullName } -Recurse -Force
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (3.4.0:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester: The directory is not empty.
At line:5 char:3

I've tried it running from an elevated powershell prompt, a normal powershell prompt, an elevated pwsh7.4.2 prompt and a normal one as well. I've even tried it from VSCode normal and elevated. I also tried to just delete the folder from the directory! Does anyone have any ideas? I'm out.
I even ran Get-Process -Name $ProcName | kill -force with powershell and pwsh to make sure there weren't any errant processes running amuck. I killed all versions of VSCode running too. And I, of course, rebooted.
This is the output from get-module -listavailable
get-module -listavailable | where name -EQ 'pester'


    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                          
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                          
Script     3.4.0      Pester                              {Describe, Context, It, Should...}

                                                                    


also, as an admin, I have full control over the pester folder in Program Files.

This worked!
$modulePath = "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester"
if (-not (Test-Path $modulePath)) {
    "There is no Pester folder in $modulePath, doing nothing."
    break
}

takeown /F $modulePath /A /R
icacls $modulePath /reset
icacls $modulePath /grant Administrators:'F' /inheritance:d /T
Remove-Item -Path $modulePath -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false

Then I re-installed it with Install-Module Pester -Force -Scope CurrentUser and I'm up to 5.6.1 now.

Glad you found a solution. So it was an ACL-related problem? Note that this should normally not occur, and that it's generally simplest to use Uninstall-Module, or, in PowerShell 7, Uninstall-PSResource.

@mklement0 I tried every way to use Uninstall-Module and nothing worked,  hence reverting to this.

@mklement0 Also, in my research, I think it's just a pester 3.4.0 default version issue. I used Uninstall-Module for the later versions of Pester and it worked just fine. I was just getting odd behavior and realized it was using Pester 3.4.0. I specifically tried Uninstall-Module Pester -requiredversion 3.4.0 -force and that didn't do it either so I decided to clean house and remove all of them and start from scratch.
